# Playbook directory and Inventory directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

[Here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data)
there is a sentence:

> Tip: In Ansible 1.2 or later the group_vars/ and host_vars/ directories can exist in the playbook directory OR the inventory directory. If both paths exist, variables in the playbook directory will override variables set in the inventory directory.

How can I define:

- playbook directory
- inventory directory

I'm not aware of that configuration and it seems that in my plays with Ansible I always have one dir which was in the same time playbook directory and inventory directory, but such separation could be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the inventory by pointing to either a file, a script, or a directory:

- in command-line:

  ```
  ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i /path/to/inventory
  ```
- [in `ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#inventory):

  ```
  inventory = /path/to/inventory
  ```

  Regardless of which option you use the **inventory directory** will be the one in which the used inventory file is stored.

And the **playbook directory** is simply the one in which the playbook is stored.

Comment: I thought that -i set inventory file not directory, but i used it a lot and I wasn't aware consequences

Comment: @itiic it seems to me that if you only specify the directory, ansible will look for hosts in files that don't have any file format. I tried it like this:
hosts location: `inventories/production/hosts.ini,` command: `ansible-playbook -i inventories/production playbook.yml` it did **not work**. But if I **remove the .ini** file format ansible will find the hosts. More over it will find all the hosts if you have them in separate files.

Comment: In order for that line in ansible.cfg to work it MUST be in the `[defaults]` section or ansible will refuse to use it

Answer (score 3):

@Miklos Kosarkar, I know this is an old post, however this was never answered.  By default, Ansible ignores certain file extensions when it looks for inventory files.  This is set in the [inventory] section of ansible.cfg.

```
[inventory]
# enable inventory plugins, default: 'host_list', 'script', 'auto', 'yaml', 'ini', 'toml'
#enable_plugins = host_list, virtualbox, yaml, constructed

# ignore these extensions when parsing a directory as inventory source
#ignore_extensions = .pyc, .pyo, .swp, .bak, ~, .rpm, .md, .txt, ~, .orig, .ini, .cfg, .retry

# ignore files matching these patterns when parsing a directory as inventory source
#ignore_patterns=

# If 'true' unparsed inventory sources become fatal errors, they are warnings otherwise.
#unparsed_is_failed=False
```